# Why I'm not able to see an Image imported using 'importXML' in my spreadsheet?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

1. I have this URL
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Gate_Bridge
2. I have this formula

> =IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HXrA.png)/table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HXrA.png)/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/img")

3. I get nothing, not even an error

[image]
Could you help to know why is this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually import the image into your sheet, you'll need to refer to the `src` and indicate you want the image imported. So something like:

```
=image(IMPORTXML(A1,"//td//a[@class='image']/img[contains(@alt,'Bridge')]/@src"))
```